# Struggling with sorting data in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an ember route that gets the following data:

```
return this.store.findAll('servicerequest');
```

One of the fields is a date field called created_at that I am trying to sort by.

Here is my servicerequest controller:

```
    import Controller from '@ember/controller';
    import { sort } from '@ember/object/computed';

    export default Controller.extend({
       appName: 'Service Requests',
       sortAscending: false,
       sortDefinition: ['created_at:desc'],
       sortedRequests: sort('servicerequest', 'sortDefinition')
    });
```

Here is the hbs section where I am outputting the data:

```
      {{#each sortedRequests as |servicerequest|}}
        {{servicerequest-list status=servicerequest.status srdescription=servicerequest.srdescription priority=servicerequest.priority created_at=servicerequest.created_at
          current_user_id=servicerequest.current_user_id servicerequestId=servicerequest.id}}
      {{/each}}
```

I have not been able to get anything to sort by the created_at field desc. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Here is my model:

```
    import DS from 'ember-data';

    export default DS.Model.extend({
      requester_name: DS.attr('string'),
      srdescription: DS.attr('string'),
      priority: DS.attr('string'),
      status: DS.attr('string'),
      created_at: DS.attr('date'),
      current_user_id: DS.attr()
    });
```

The data is coming from a rails api. The created_at field is what the systems defaults to on records that is why there is an underscore.

I am using ember-cli: 3.0.2

Comment: Could you please share your model? The code you have posted, seems to be correct for me. But maybe there is something wrong with your `created_at` property on the model. Also it seems weird to me, that your property is underscored. Normally the convention in ember.js is to have camelCased property names.

Comment: Which version of Ember are you using? I believe computed.sort was removed in 2.16

Comment: Thaks guys. I have updated the original post with the answers to your questions. Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up getting it working by doing this:

```
return this.store.findAll('servicerequest').then(results => 
results.sortBy('created_at').reverse());
```

Not sure if it is the best way but for now it's doing what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally any data operation should be performed at the backend.

Incase if there are any backend limitations, you can move the sorting logic snippet into the serializer. This way, any fetch call for 'servicerequest', will come sorted and redundant sorting logic can be avoided.

Something like =>

```
serialize(snapshot, options) {
    snapshot.sortBy('created_at').reverse();
    return this._super(...arguments);
}
```